# JQUERY/js how make dropdown menu from api response

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, drop-down-menu

Based from my code below , how can i make the newField a drop down menu textfield like this [image: sample] [image: another sample]cause now it is still a textfield . Then the value is the list of "title" from this rest api https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. Thanks

```
var addRuleLink = $("<a>", {"href": "#", "class": "add-rule", "text": "Add Condition"});
      var _this = this;
      addRuleLink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = _this.fields[0];
        var newField = {name: f.value, operator: f.operators[0], value: null};
        div.append(_this.buildRule(newField));
      });
      div.append(addRuleLink);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a autocomplete feature? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: not auto complete but a dropdown

Comment: a dropdown list